# how to change data inside function

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function that changes the value of a data frame.

this is the .csv file: `income.raw`

```
month, category, occurrence
4, .hagwon, 3.33
5, .hagwon, 11.33
6, .hagwon, 10
6, .co, 5
```

and this is the function i'm trying to make:

```
workDone <- function(time, work, plus) {
  
  function.income <- income.raw
  for (a in length(function.income$month)) {
    if (identical(time, function.income$month[a]) & identical(work, function.income$category[a])) {
      function.income$occurrence[a] <- function.income$occurrence[a] + plus
      break
    }
  }
  
  return.value <- function.income %>%
      mutate("total" = case_when (category == ".hagwon" ~ (occurrence * 17000 * 3)
                                  ,category == ".co" ~ (occurrence * 30000 * 2))) %>%
      mutate("before.tax" = total, "after.tax" = total * 0.967) %>%
      group_by(month) %>% 
      mutate("monthly.total" = sum(after.tax, na.rm = TRUE))

  return(return.value)  
}
```

even though I used `break` and I tried to use `<<-`, neither worked.

I'm trying to replace a certain part of `income.raw$occurrence` and the mutate() would calculate the income with the changed value.

Comment: Edit the function so it takes `income.raw` as a parameter. It's much better and safer than messing with global state. And assign the result of the function back: `income.raw <- workDone(income.raw, time, work, plus)`.

Comment: did you miss `1:length(function.income$month)` in `for ()`?